# Calculating capacitor current

Tags: capacitor, current, power-factor-correction

I have attempted a question (attached below) which is in 3 parts: 
First, find new current with new power factor,
Second, find capacitor current.
Third, enter image description here the value of the capacitor.
[image]
[image]

The first element I have an answer of 27.34A using \$(P=v i \cos(\phi) )\$ however the issue is:
How do I calculate the capacitor current before the value of the capacitor as they are asked in this order?

I know how to find the Value of the capacitor then the current across but not in this order also the method used is quite long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the load. ArcCos of 0.75 is 41.41 degrees. Work out the equivalent parallel R and L currents. I get I_R = 26.25 amps and no matter what you do with the capacitor this will always be 26.25 amps. I_L I get to be 23.15 amps (35 x Sin(41.41)).

What will be the net reactive current with the capacitor fitted comes next. At a PF of 0.96 the angle is 16.26 degrees. So take the Tan of 16.26 and using I_R calculate the net reactive current. I get 7.66 amps.

The capacitor current is exactly opposing (and cancelling) the inductor current so the current taken by the capacitor is 23.15 amps - 7.66 amps = 15.49 amps.

Using V, F and 15.49 amps I calculate capacitance to be 205 uF.

It all helps if you draw a phasor diagram then you can see why I have used tan and sin in various places. Let me know if you are having problems with that.

Comment: thank-you for the answer this has been of great help one part i m having trouble still understandings the top paragraph as to why the Parallel L and R currents as there is no mention of an inductor (L)?

Comment: If the original PF is lagging there has to be an inductor so, modelling the load as a parallel RL is perfectly ok. If the shoe fits etc..